# How to setup a ListView that get its data from a server

Tags: android, listview, layout

I've been trying to find a tutorial of how to create a ListView that get its data from a server dynamically as it's scrolled.  I have not been able to find complete documents of how to do this.  Only small examples or ListView tutorials that deals with set arrays.  This has left me where I don't know where to start building the ListView code.

I have some code that gets data from the server.  I also do have all the layouts and basic Activity code.

- How/what do ListView do to get one more rows as it is scrolled?
- And when I need to have different row layouts. How do ListView handles this?

Is there a complete tutorial that deals with ListView and getting data from a server?

Comment: What you are suggesting (getting ListView rows as needed when scrolling) doesn't seem like a very good idea to me. What if the user performs an upward 'fling'? If you've only populated the ListView with enough rows to fill the screen, then nothing will happen. Even if the user simply performs a 'quick' upward drag of the ListView, you'll need to pull rows at quite a rate to keep up. Also, what happens to the data which scrolls off the top or bottom of the screen? Are you going to simply discard it and have to download again later? Perhaps you can explain a little further.

Answer (score 0):

> How/what do ListView do to get one more rows as it is scrolled?

There is nothing built into Android for this. You could use my [`EndlessAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless), either directly or as an idea of how to accomplish similar ends in your own code.

> And when I need to have different row layouts. How do ListView handles this?

You need to implement an appropriate `ListAdapter`, one that has proper implementations of `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()`.

> Is there a complete tutorial that deals with ListView and getting data from a server?

Along with your other two bullets? Probably not. Your requirements are individually uncommon and are even less common in conjunction.

Comment: Then how do Market do it? You can scroll to the end of next year and it will keep filling the list as you scroll. Also I got the idea that ListView can do it by watching this: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html. It just doesn't give a complete example I can follow.

Comment: @Espen: Market does it because its developers wrote code to do that, just like I wrote code to do that with `EndlessAdapter`, as mentioned (and linked to) in my answer. It is not built into the operating system. "It just doesn't give a complete example I can follow" -- you have indicated you want a "complete tutorial" that covers endless lists with multiple row types populated from a server. You probably will not find that. You can find sample code for the individual facets (endlessness, multiple row types, server) easily enough. It will be up to you to combine them.